# Excel users get error message when opening files located on Windows server

Tags: microsoft-excel

We recently copied all of the shared files for one of our departments from a Sharepoint 2010 document repository to a regular Windows shared folder on a Windows 2008 R2 server.  When people try to open some files, they get an error message which states:

is locked for editing by "another user".  They are then given the options open read-only, notify or cancel.

The users are running 32-bit Office 2010 on Windows 7 x64.

The strange thing is that only some people have this problem.  For instance, for a given file User A and User B can open the file with no trouble but User C gets this error message when they try to open the file.

While trying to open the file for a user that is experiencing this problem, I've logged in to the file server and verified that no one else has that file open using "manage open files" under Server Manager > Roles > File Services > Share and Storage Management.

There's also no owner file present in the folder the spreadsheet is stored in.

I've tried saving documents to the desktop, opening them, then saving back to the shared drive with a different file name, but that doesn't seem to help.

I've deleted files stored in the temp folder on the PC where this error is happening but that didn't make any difference.

All of the folks that are trying to open these files have Full Control NTFS permissions and Full Control on the file share itself.  The permissions are controlled by an Active Directory group for that department.  Some users in the AD group can access the files fine while other's can't, so it doesn't seem like this could be a permissions-related issue.  Furthermore, if users experiencing the problem manually copy a problematic file from the server to their desktop, they can open it.

I'm at a loss as to what my next step should be.

Comment: real-time A/V running on the server?  Creator Owner or System listed in the NTFS permissions?

Comment: How is the network connection speed between the file server and the users? Are these users in another location?